# Viable solution to provide contact form service?

Tags: email, webforms, contact-form, wufoo, formstack

My goal is to provide each of my users a web page that contains a contact form.

The contact form would have one key parameter: the destination address where my user wants to receive all contacts entries.

---

So the form would look like:

Name:

Email:

Message:

[+hidden parameter: destination email address where to send this contact on submit]

---

My main concern is to have the emails considered spam because of the technology choice, or even because the system might be abused in some way.

I thought of using Wufoo API, but it doesn't look like I can automatically create a form for each of my users. Formstack API does look more promising (I found a ['create form' method](http://developers.formstack.com/api-docs/methods/createform/)). Also I found a [non-official? Google Form API](http://code.lancepollard.com/introducing-the-google-form-api/) which looks interesting.

Would you know a viable solution to do provide contact form service to users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a while it came down to me that what I actually needed was simply an API to send emails, because the form part is simple and doesn't require any API.

All I need is a *`sendEmail ($source, $destination, $subject, $body)`* type of API.

For this I found the [Amazon Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) a great solution.